# Adding Thirty years to date field using ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, date

I have 2 fields one is Creation Date the other is Maintenance Date. The Maintenance Date should be 30 years after the Creation date.

I have been trying to use the field calculator for this. But I haven't been able to make this work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Some things I found online. But Khibma answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to "Add" dates. Here's one in CalculateField (place these values into the last 2 boxes of the tool, updating the CreationDateField with your field name).

Field to update:

`add30(!CreationDateField!)`

Code Block:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def add30(start):
    update = start + relativedelta(years=30)
    return update
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394327/using-datetime-timedelta-to-add-years

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!